# Flask-ask Cannot Deploy zappa

Tags: python, pip, aws-lambda, zappa

I was trying to deploy flask-ask alexa skill using Zappa. 
I followed the instructions on [Alexa Tutorial: Deploy Flask-Ask Skills to AWS Lambda with Zappa`](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/8e8ad73a-99e9-4c0f-a7b3-60f92287b0bf/new-alexa-tutorial-deploy-flask-ask-skills-to-aws-lambda-with-zappa)
But I'm getting a

```
 KeyError: pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib.
```

when I run: `zappa deploy dev`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a [bug #5079 in pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5079). Please verify with `pip --version` that you have `pip` version 9.0.2, then downgrade to 9.0.1:

```
pip install -U pip==9.0.1
```

Comment: worked fine for me with pip 9.0.3 but I had to downgrade cryptography to 2.1.4 as @Oemer mentioned.

`pip install -U cryptography==2.1.4` and then `zappa update dev`

Comment: The bug was fixed in pip 9.0.3. Problematic version is only 9.0.2.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. But "upgrading" to pip 9.0.1 worked for me.

Now I am facing another issue: After deploying with zappa I always get an HTTP 500 error by testing the alexa skill. I used zappa tail and figured out following error:

```
[1521581897750] File "/private/var/folders/8g/t93g7k9j0rb_18d07m1k8shr0000gn/T/pip-build-SO5htj/pyOpenSSL/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 740, in _subjectAltNameString
[1521581897750] AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509V3_EXT_get'
[1521581897751] [INFO] 2018-03-20T21:38:17.751Z 005fde13-2c87-11e8-ac0a-8b163e7315d5 72.21.217.134 - - [20/Mar/2018:21:38:17 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 291 "" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (Java/1.8.0_131)" 0/390.608
```

Comment: downgrading cryptography to version 2.1.4 worked for me.